# MPI Gaussian elimination in C with each processor reading from file

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to perform a Gaussian elimination using MPI, of which I am very new to. From what I know, the forward elimination is what can be done in parallel, whereas the backward substitution can be done on the main processor due to the communication cost.

In the code below I've tried to implement it but it seems like I have some sort of communication error going on when perfomring forward elimination. The input matrix is of the for N*(N+1) as it read as an augmented matrix. Each processor is supposed to read its share of the matrix so processors would need to send values accordingly.

The input matrix is specified as a file of the following format:

```
6.807000 5.249000 0.073000 3.658000 8.930000 1.272000 7.544000 0.878000 1.000000
7.709000 4.440000 8.165000 4.492000 3.042000 7.987000 2.503000 2.327000 2.000000
8.840000 2.612000 4.303000 3.169000 7.709000 7.157000 9.560000 0.933000 3.000000
0.278000 1.816000 5.335000 9.097000 7.826000 3.512000 9.267000 3.810000 4.000000
0.979000 9.149000 6.579000 8.821000 1.967000 0.672000 1.393000 9.336000 5.000000
1.745000 5.228000 4.091000 0.194000 6.357000 5.001000 1.153000 6.708000 6.000000
5.668000 1.490000 8.124000 2.196000 9.530000 0.903000 7.722000 4.666000 7.000000
8.024000 7.801000 6.853000 0.977000 7.408000 8.228000 4.933000 0.298000 8.000000
```

The resulting matrix should like this:

```
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.733315 
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.806801 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.843402 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.912938 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.146581 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.048743 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.849379 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -0.002284
```

However, what I get is:

```
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -nan 
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -nan 
7.431000 2.624000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -nan 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -nan 
3.714586 -0.915696 -1.032000 -5.928000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -nan 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -nan 
-8.653789 -0.773373 1.057501 6.074484 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 -nan 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -nan
```

Can anybody provide some insight as to what is going wrong? I thought to use barriers to make sure that the processors don't start until all processes have read their share of the matrix from the file. There is another barrier after forward elimination to ensure that all processors have finished before performing backward substitution. Are these barriers required?

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "math.h"
#include "mpi.h"

#define SUCCESS 0
#define ERROR -1

#define EPSILON 0.000001

void read_matrix_size_from_file(char *filename, int *rows, int *columns);
double ** read_user_matrix_from_file(char *filename, int rows, int columns, int rank, int nprocs);
double ** allocate_matrix(int, int);
void free_matrix(double **matrix, int rows);
void divide_by_max(double **, int, int);
void input_clicking_probabilities(double **, int, int, double *);
void write_clicking_probabilities_to_file(double *cp, int rows);
void print_best_acceptance_threshold(double *, int);
void print_matrix(double **, int, int);

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("please provide a user matrix!\n");
        return ERROR;
    }

    /* init */
    int rank, nprocs;
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
    clock_t begin1, end1, begin2, end2;

    /* setup */
    int rows, columns;
    double **A;
    double *cp;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("malloc cp process %d\n", rank); 
        read_matrix_size_from_file(argv[1], &rows, &columns);
        cp = malloc(columns * sizeof(double));
    }
    /* Each process will read its own subset of the larger matrix */


    MPI_Bcast(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&columns, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    /* Split the matrix into submatrixs */
    //int rpp = rows / rank;
    //int rrpp = rows % rank;
    printf("WE reached here process %d\n", rank);

    int i,j,k;
    int *map = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);

    int stop = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<nprocs; i++)
        {
            if (rank == i)
            {
                printf("Reading for process %d\n", rank);
                A = read_user_matrix_from_file(argv[1], rows, columns, rank, nprocs);
                stop = 1;
            }   
        }
        if (stop)
        {
            break;
        }
    }




    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        map[i] = i % nprocs;
    }
    printf("Process %d is here\n", rank);

    for(k=0; k<rows; k++)
    {
        //printf("Broadcast recieved/sent in process %d from %d\n", rank, map[k]);
        MPI_Bcast (&A[k][k],rows-k,MPI_DOUBLE,map[k],MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("process %d, broadcast b[%d] as %G\n", rank,k,A[k][columns-1] );
        MPI_Bcast (&A[k][columns-1],1,MPI_DOUBLE,map[k],MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        double pivot;
        for(i= k+1; i<rows; i++) 
    {
      if(map[i] == rank)
      {
          pivot = A[i][k]/A[k][k];
      }
    }               
    for(i= k+1; i<rows; i++) 
    {       
      if(map[i] == rank)
      {
        for(j=0;j<rows;j++)
        {
            A[i][j]=A[i][j]-( pivot * A[k][j] );
        }
        A[i][columns-1]= A[i][columns-1]-( pivot * A[k][columns-1] );
        printf("b[%d] is %G\n", i, A[i][columns-1]);
      }
    }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Process %d finished\n", rank);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
            /* Back-substitution */
        int row,row2;
        for (row = rows-1; row >= 0; row--) {
            A[row][columns-1] = A[row][columns-1] / A[row][row];
            printf("divide %G by %G\n",A[row][columns-1] , A[row][row]);
            A[row][row] = 1;
            for (row2 = row-1; row2 >= 0; row2--) {
                A[row2][columns-1] += A[row2][row]*A[row][columns-1];
                A[row2][row] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        print_matrix(A, rows, columns);
        divide_by_max(A, rows, columns);
        /* results */
        input_clicking_probabilities(A, rows, columns, cp);
        print_best_acceptance_threshold(cp, rows);
        write_clicking_probabilities_to_file(cp, rows);
        printf("Free cp process %d\n", rank);
        free(cp);
        printf("Freed cp\n");
    }

    /* results */
    free_matrix(A, rows);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return SUCCESS;

}


void read_matrix_size_from_file(char *filename, int *rows, int *columns)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    /* get number of rows and columns*/
    *rows = 1;
    *columns = 1;
    char c;
    int columns_known = 0;
    while(!feof(file)) {
        c = fgetc(file);
        if (c == ' ') {
            if (!columns_known) (*columns)++;
        } 

        if (c == '\n') {
            (*rows)++;
            columns_known = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    printf("There are %d rows and %d columns\n", *rows, *columns);

    fclose(file);
}

double ** read_user_matrix_from_file(char *filename, int rows, int columns, int rank, int nprocs)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    /* read values into an array */
    //rewind(file);
    printf("Rank is %d\n", rank);
    printf("Nprocess is %d\n", nprocs);
    printf("Rows is %d and columns is %d\n", rows, columns);
    double **matrix = allocate_matrix(rows, columns);
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        if (rank == i % nprocs)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(file);

    return matrix;
}

double ** allocate_matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    double ** matrix = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *) * rows);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * columns);
    }

    return matrix;
}

void free_matrix(double **matrix, int rows)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

void input_clicking_probabilities(double **matrix, int rows, int columns, double *cp) {
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        cp[row] = matrix[row][columns-1];
    }
}

void write_clicking_probabilities_to_file(double *cp, int rows)
{
    /* write clicking probabilities to file */ 
    FILE *output_file;
    int row;
    output_file = fopen("clicking_probabilities.txt","w");
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        fprintf(output_file, "%lf\n", cp[row]);
    }

    fclose(output_file);
}

void print_matrix(double **matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    FILE *output_file;
    int row, column;
    output_file = fopen("row_reduced_matrix.txt","w");
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            fprintf(output_file,"%lf ",matrix[row][column]);
        }
        fprintf(output_file,"\n");
    }   
    fclose(output_file);
}

void print_best_acceptance_threshold(double *cp, int rows) {

}

void divide_by_max(double **matrix, int rows, int columns) {
    double max = 0; 
    int row, column;

    /* get max so we can divide by this later to get probabilities */
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {      
        if (max < fabs(matrix[row][columns-1])) max = fabs(matrix[row][columns-1]);
    }

    /* divide by max and take abs */
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        /* check for division by zero */
        if (equals(max,0)) {
            matrix[row][columns-1] = 0;
        } else {
            matrix[row][columns-1] = fabs (matrix[row][columns-1]) / max;
        }
    }
}

int equals(double a, double b) {
    if (fabs(a-b) < EPSILON) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you try to parallelize something, you should use mutex, barriers and other tools like them properly, if not your solution will not be more performante than a sequential form.

You have too many code but what I can suggest you is to test your code with one process and see if you have the same error. If you have the same error it means that it's in your calculation and your logic. But if your bug desapear it means that somewhere you dont communicate the good information between processes.

Comment: two observations after a quick look at your code: your last column is full of `NaN`s. Probably, you're dividing some numbers by zero. Secondly, since you're using only blocking MPI functions, they act like barriers - every process waits for the last one to finish before they can all proceed. Hope these small insights help a bit.

Comment: I have it working with 1 process, but it doesn't seem to work with two. Am I broadcasting  the values correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the results above (the NAN) was reading from the file. In the read_user_matrix_from_file function, there is a for loop with a fscanf. Note that incrementing the loop does **NOT** increment the file pointer. The issues was fixed by incrementing the file pointer by reading the line (not into the file pointer). There is probably a more efficient way to do it, but for simplicities sake, that's what can be done. Also note that the barriers are not required because of MPI_Bcast being a blocking call. The loop to read from a file should look something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("process %d, %d mod %d = %d\n", world_rank, i, nprocs, i% nprocs);
        if (world_rank == i % nprocs)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }else {
            for ( j= 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%lf", &buf[j]);
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }
```